# Cómo puedo sacar archivos de una carpeta con js del frontent

Tags: javascript

No puedo encontrar la forma de sacar archivos de una carpeta con js del fronten sin usar node, e estado buscando y no encuentro la forma abra alguna api de js o un freinguort que me pueda ayudar a esto.

Lo que quiero hacer es que cuando coloques una carpeta te pueda mostrar todos los archivos que tiene y bueno si hay otra carpeta dentro de esa sacar esos archivos también, si alguien sabe como me podría dar un ejemplo.

```js
soltarArchivos(e) {
            e.preventDefault()
            const archivo = e.dataTransfer.files
            const file = new FileReader()

            for (let i = 0; i < archivo.length; i++) {
                console.log(archivo[i])
            }

            /* file.onload = e => {
                const text = e
                console.log(text)
            }
            file.readAsArrayBuffer(archivo)*/
        },
```

```html
<div @drop="soltarArchivos(event)"
                            @dragover.preventDefault="prevenirevento"
                            class="contenedor col-12">
                                <div class="img d-flex justify-content-center">
                                    <img src="./assets/16 (5).png">
                                </div>
                                <div class="lista row">
                                    <div class="col-10 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                                        <!-- maximo de miniaturas 7 -->
                                        <div class="miniatura">
                                            <img src="./assets/16 (5).png">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="miniatura tamaño">
                                            <span>+</span><br>
                                            <p>agrege otro archivo</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-2 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                                        <button class="btn btn-outline-light">enviar -></button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Comment: Javascript está más orientado a trabajar con herramientas cliente, te recomiendo en su lugar ocupar php para tu propósito general

Comment: No uso node porque yo no me encargo del bakent y lo que hago es subir archivos para que el servidor los guarde, pero tengo que detectar cuando alguien sube una carpeta y subir todos los archivos que contiene adentro

Comment: lo único que quiero es detectar cuando suben carpetas y subir todos los archivos que llevan dentro para subirlo al servidor, no pienso hacer nada más complejos sólo subir todos los archivos que tenga esa carpeta para luego desirle al servidor que archivos estaba dentro y como se llamaba esa carpeta y el servidor se encarga del resto

Answer (score 1):

La [API File (acceso a archivos)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications) permite seleccionar una carpeta y recorrer su contenido como una lista. El siguiente ejemplo permite obtener la lista de archivos al seleccionar una carpeta (el atributo `directory` permite seleccionar una carpeta en vez de archivos).

```html
<input type="file" name="files" webkitdirectory directory id="files" multiple />


<script>
var inp = document.getElementById("files");
inp.addEventListener("change",function(ev){
  //console.log(inp.files);
  for (i = 0; i < inp.files.length; i++) {
      let file = inp.files[i];
      console.log(file.name, file.webkitRelativePath, file.size);
  }

});
</script>
```

Cabe destacar que solo se tiene acceso al contenido de la carpeta que el usuario elige y las rutas son *relativas* a dicha carpeta, no absolutas.

Esite tambien el [atributo `alowDirs`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#Properties) para usar en vez de `directory webkitdirectory` permitir tanto *archivos individuales como directorios*.

Finalmente, indicar que la APi especifica para manejo de carpetas (Directory Upload API) esta en progreso y aun varios navegadores no la implementan (Ver https://caniuse.com/?search=webkitdirectory)

Comment: funciona bien con los inputs pero cuando lo arrastro a un div no :(
el div puede resibir archivos con un evennto que le puse pero con las carpetas las mira como un archivo normal

Comment: Aqui hay un ejemplo usando un polyfill para permitir arrastrar directorios (segun dice esto funciona para chrome por lo menos) https://wicg.github.io/directory-upload/

Comment: en el ejemplo funciona
pero lo copie aparte para mirar y probar el código y no funcionaba gracias de todas formas :)

Comment: Intenta copiando tambien el polifill.js https://wicg.github.io/directory-upload/polyfill.js este es clave para que funcione

Comment: Sigue igual :( talvez deba probar algo diferente